# Populating form on keydown ENTER and preventing form from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events, onsubmit

JS

```
$('.add_to_list').live('keydown',function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == '13'){
        var holder=$(this).attr('hold'),
            val=$(this).val();
            if(holder == 'mf' ||holder == 'mp'){
                    var v='#'+holder;   
                    h='<li class="entery deletable"><input type="hidden" name="'+holder+'[]" value="'+val+'">'+val+'</li>';
                    $(v).append(h);
                    $(this).val('');
            }
        e.prevent_default();    
        return false;
    }
    $('#save_clinic').submit(function(){return false;});
    });
```

HTML

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="save_clinic" action="#">
<p>
<b>Findings</b>
<ol id='mf'></ol>
<input type="text" hold="mf" class="add_to_list" value="" name="">
<!--the input hv no name cause i dont want it to be submitted, this is for adding only-->
</p>
<p>
<b>Medical Procedures:</b>
<ol id=mp></ol>
<input type="text" hold="mp" class="add_to_list" value="" name="">
<!--the input hv no name cause i dont want it to be submitted, this is for adding only-->
</p>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Problem:
I want to prevent submit on keypress <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and only allow submit on submit button click,
but my current js prevent submit for both and if I remove

```
$('#save_clinic').submit(function(){return false;});
```

from js then the form auto submit when user is trying to populate the form.

Can some one  please tell me what is the problem here?
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/cheeken/Wuun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) (no underscore, capital 'D'), not `prevent_default`. Give that a try and remove this line:

```
$('#save_clinic').submit(function(){return false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be outside:

```
$('.add_to_list').live('keydown',function (e){
   if(e.keyCode == '13'){
    var holder=$(this).attr('hold'),
        val=$(this).val();
        if(holder == 'mf' ||holder == 'mp'){
                var v='#'+holder;   
                h='<li class="entery deletable"><input type="hidden" name="'+holder+'[]" value="'+val+'">'+val+'</li>';
                $(v).append(h);
                $(this).val('');
        }
   }
   e.prevent_default(); // take this out from the if   
   $('#save_clinic').submit(function(){return false;});
});
```

Comment: where is the form in this fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add_to_list').live('keydown',function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == '13'){
            var holder=$(this).attr('hold'),
                val=$(this).val();
                if(holder == 'mf' ||holder == 'mp' ||holder == 'orders'){
                        var v='#'+holder;   
                        h='<li class="entery deletable"><input type="hidden" name="'+holder+'[]" value="'+val+'">'+val+'</li>';
                        $(v).append(h);
                        $(this).val('');
                }
            //return false;
            e.preventDefault();
```

AND
http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Disable-Form-Submit-on-Enter-Key-Press.aspx

both works fine now.. thanks all